# Difficulty with global and local variable example from Sam's Teach yourself

Tags: javascript

I load this in my chrome browser and it just shows a blank page. The other examples have worked for me thus far, not sure what I'm messing up on here. Please help, thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Variable Scope</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var a = 10;
var b = 10;  
function showVars() {
var a = 20;
b = 20;
return  "Local variable 'a' = " + a + "\nGlobal variable 'b' =
" + b;
}
var message = showVars();
alert(message+ "n\Global variable 'a' = " + a);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Strings cant be multiline. [Just use `` instead of "" to make it work](http://jsbin.com/fumilocogo/1/edit?console), or [remove the newline](http://jsbin.com/feqohetumi/edit?console)

Comment: just move return statement to one line, string can't be multiline here. https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/1545/

Comment: vital to start learning how to read errors in the browser console. A web search for most errors will often help you understand them better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page will be blank because your HTML element is empty.
About the JavaScript code; Strings can be sent through one line when using double-quotes. Consider using ` instead, or just write your string in one line..